# Shuffle the rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab

How to I shuffle the order of the rows of a matrix

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
5 1 3 2 4 6
2 5 1 3 4 6
```

I need to shuffle the ordering of the rows

```
2 5 1 3 4 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
5 1 3 2 4 6
```

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: it is really not clear what are you trying to do. Please provide more information: do you need to shuffle the rows randomly?

Comment: yes i need to shuffle the rows randomly, YUP

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB at the moment, so I can only give you an outline of a method: use `randperm(3)` to generate a permutation of indices, then create a new matrix by assigning each row of your matrix to the new one in the sequence returned by randperm.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use a random permutation ([`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)) of the row indices to shuffle the rows of your input matrix.

As an example I have used `magic` but substitute your matrix in for `A`.

```
A = magic(3);
%// 8     1     6
%// 3     5     7
%// 4     9     2

rows = randperm(size(A, 1));
%// 2     1     3

B = A(rows, :);
%// 3     5     7
%// 8     1     6
%// 4     9     2
```

Or in one line:

```
B = A(randperm(size(A, 1)), :);
```